# Get Aspnet Repeater Current Item Property Value in page

Tags: asp.net, repeater, asprepeater

I need to get the current item property value inside an aspnet repeater, so I can do an if else, like so:

```
  <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeaterLeftMenu" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceMenuPrincipalEsquerda">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" id='<%# Eval("item_sid") %>' onclick='clickLeftMainMenu("<%# Eval("item_sid") %>")' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="" data-original-title='<%# Eval("item_desig") %>'>
                                <% if(Current Item property) { %>
                                <img src='../images/first_menu_vertical/<%# Eval("item_img") %>' />
                                <%else { %>
                                <img src='../images/menu/<%# Eval("item_icon") %>' />
                               <% } %>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

I'm, stuck on getting the current item property part.
I wanted to do this whitout codebehind, if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "property"? Why not use `if (Eval("item_sid").ToString() == "value")`

Comment: Tried it. It throws a System.InvalidOperationException